# Interpretation R results linear Model with Interactions

Tags: r, regression, interaction, interpretation

I'm trying to analyse the effects of testosterone in combination with a specific pill type can have on reaction times.

For example, if there is a difference in the reaction times between people who have low testosterone levels and take a specific pill, a low testosterone level, and they don't take a pill, a high testosterone level and a specific pill and a high testosterone level and no pill.

So I am specifically interested in the effects the **interaction of the pill** (I have 3 “types” antiandrogen, androgen and no pill)**and the testosterone level** on the reaction times. Therefore, I used a linear (T- tests did not work because of the sample size) model in R but I struggle with the interpretation.

[image]

What exactly do I see there e.g. in the brackets? How I could interpret the results (that refer to the interaction)?

Thanks in advance for any help.
I'll appreciate a lot

[image]

Comment: This is more of stats question, which would be more of a questions for stackexchange.com. However, could you provide a sample of your data and the script that produces those results? I think you may want to use the `summary` function to get what you need.

Comment: Hi Lyn, can you provide more information? It's hard to tell what is the model you have just from the screen shot alone.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answers and moving my question to the right place. I edited the question and added a screenshot of my R- Script. Since my original data file is quite big I don´t know how i could include it but my data consists manly of reaction times in ms to different stimuli conditions and cathegories (testosterone level "T_Spiegel" low"niedrig"/high"hoch") and type of pill (antiandrogen/androgen/no pill "keine") Was this usefull?

Comment: Oh my question refers to 5.3 "Regressionen uber alle abhaengigen Variablen"